# Autoprefixer does not work on Sublime

Tags: macos, css, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I following this [link](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-automatic-vendor-prefix/) to add AutoPrefixer plugin to my sublimeText.

Once I press 'Cmd + Shift + P', AutoPrefix CSS is one option of the menu. However, when I choose it nothing happens.

I have a simple css for testing:

```
div{
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

Node.js version is v0.12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your are based on default settings. AutoPrefixer default version is 2.0.

Go to

> Preferences > Package Settings > Autoprefixer > Settings - User

and paste following to cover more versions.

```
{
    "browsers": ["last 7 versions"],
    "cascade": true,
    "remove": true
}
```